# Unable to create hibernate.cfg.xml through eclipse wizard?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

The eclipse wizard that is supposed to guide me through creating a hibernate configuration file greys out its Next button, until I manually check the option to generate a Console Configuration. Is this how it works?

Next, I get into the Create Hibernate Console Configuration wizard, which has the same problem: I complete its Main tab, Next remains grey, and Finish does nothing for me. I expect to see some kind of warning as to what is missing here, but the wizard is not very helpful here.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the JBoss Tools Create Hibernate Configuration Wizard: pressing Finish generates an unhandled event loop exception in eclipse. A workaround is to select an older hibernate version.